# Loading dynamically created textures in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, texture2d

I'm creating a project in Unity using Vuforia and it lets people dynamically creates trackable images and then lets you create a display. These images and displays are converted into textures and applied to quads as a material.

I'm trying to make it so when the textures are created, they are saved so when the app is restarted they are stored and remembered. So far I have the code

```
private void SaveTexturesToJpg(Texture2D textureToSave)
{
    byte[] bytes = textureToSave.EncodeToJPG();
    string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/JPG_" + _nameCounter + ".jpg";
    _nameCounter++;
    File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, bytes);
}
```

This saves the texture to a folder in the device, I know I can use `File.ReadAllBytes()` to load the image but I do not understand how to apply this as a texture.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could/should directly use [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) it also works on local files ;)

Comment: Also rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) it uses the correct path separators according to the platform your app is later running on.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a byte array with your texture data you can load the data into your texture  with `LoadRawTextureData()`

first create your texture with the size and format you need and after load in the data. A  512x512 texture without mipmap would be something like that:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512, 512, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
tex.LoadRawTextureData(dataArray);
tex.Apply();
```

after that you can just apply the texture to your material

Comment: Be careful with the TextureFormat as well .. it has to match the source texture